# Team City - Add Gallio test result xml to build display

Tags: nunit, teamcity, gallio, build-server

Im using TeamCity with `Gallio/XUnit/Specflow` and trying to display our unit/acceptance test results. I believe the output is `NUnit` xml test result format.

Our unit tests auotmatically display using the command runner with Gallio. The acceptance tests are run through a large Powershell script which calls Gallio (Run-Gallio).

Results are output to acceptance-test-results.xml. Is there a way to display the acceptance-test-results.xml in `TeamCity (6.5.5)`?

Comment: You forgot to specify version of `TeamCity` since different versions support different set of report formats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this in a PowerShell script add the following

```
 Write-Output "##teamcity[importData type='nunit' path='C:\SomeDirectory\YourResults.xml']"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use built in TeamCity feature `importdata` service message:

```xml
 <!-- Send to TeamCity a service message using MSBuild -->
<Message Text="##teamcity[importData 
                          type='nunit' 
                          path='$(OutputPath)\UnitTestsReport.xml']" 
         Importance="High" />
```

For more details see: [Build Script Interaction with TeamCity - Importing XML Reports](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ImportingXMLReports)

Answer (score 0):

Thought this might be useful also for other people that came to this SO post with slightly different requirements. It's the public wiki for TC that covers this particular area.

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ImportingXMLReports