# How can i show DUnitX results on TeamCity

Tags: delphi, teamcity, dunitx

I have been trying to fiddle around within my instance of TeamCity to try and get a **Tests** tab to display at the end of each build. My current build configuration is as follows:

- [Powershell] Set version of delphi application
- [Command Line] Build application dproj
- [Command Line] Build dunitx-test dproj && run dunitx executable
- [Powershell] Zip contents -> Create nuget package
- [Octopus] Publish
- Publish to TeamCity *dunitx-results.xml*

Reading through the [DUnitX Documentation](https://github.com/VSoftTechnologies/DUnitX) they state that the output is compatible with NUnit. So what I am trying to do is at the end of the building process that TeamCity displays my test results on its own tab. Similar to how NUnit tests results are exposed after a Visual Studio Build using NUnit or MSTest.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this, or get a similar output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this helps anyone else, I was able to get the **Tests** to finally show thanks to the responses found in this questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412815/team-city-add-gallio-test-result-xml-to-build-display?rq=1)

TeamCity lets you output to the screen content based on its own commands in several different ways explained in their [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity).

Since I am running my tests from the command line I just had to add the following line to my **Test Step**

> echo ##teamcity[importData type='nunit' path='Tests\Win32\Release\bin\dunitx-results.xml']